# Web workers shared memory

Tags: concurrency, web-worker

Is it possible to share memory between several web workers for reading and writing(or at least for reading only) in the modern browsers? If not, are there plans to implement such feature?

I know that data may be transferred between workers by using message system, but such way sometimes is not suitable, for instance because of serialization overhead of large data structures.

Comment: I hope not. Mutability in a multithreaded environment only brings complexity. Too many cooks spoil the broth, and all that. You should probably have a single thread manage each dataset, while providing an API for getting access from other threads to specific parts of data. My 0.02€

Comment: @Zecc: As far as I understand current implementation of web workers doesn't allow getting access from other threads to specific parts of data in main thread without serialization of that parts(am I right?). It makes a huge overhead when working with large part of data(for instance, it has sense in concurrent compilation problem). BTW, I prefer immutable-way of working with data too, but it doesn't contradict ability of using shared memory, i.e. shared memory may be immutable as well.

Answer (score 0):

There is no shared memory. It's by definition that we wish each worker ('thread') will have its own arena to live in. However, currently you can use WebSQL are you shared local location BUT it's not wise since it's not thread safe. 
In the future we might be able to use indexedDB (WHEN it will be implemented!)

You might want to check the other way around and use Shared Workers. This will give you the way to leverage the same worker from several tabs/windows of your app. I'm not sure if it will fit you case...

Comment: Ido, thank you for your reply. I'm not sure, but I don't think Shared workers relate to this topic. Could you please explain how IndexedDB might solve shared memory issue more detailed or provide a link?

Comment: @Eliah - I guess you right about shared workers... As for IndexedDB - once it will be implemented (like we have today the FileSystem API:
http://www.w3.org/TR/file-system-api/#using-localfilesystem ) you could use this as 'source of true' for all your workers to share data. Make sense?

Comment: but that doesn't really share the memory either.

if you spend more time serializing the data than processing it - not to mention memory duplication or quadruplication use - then spawning that worker becomes quickly very pointless.